# Amazon AWS Access to Feeds.SubmitFeed is denied

Tags: php, amazon-mws

My API request is this (excerpt):

```
   [method] => POST
    [uri] => Array
        (
            [scheme] => https
            [host] => mws.amazonservices.com
            [port] => 443
            [user] => 
            [pass] => 
            [path] => /
            [query] => Array
                (
                    [AWSAccessKeyId] => xxx
                    [Action] => SubmitFeed
                    [FeedType] => _POST_FLAT_FILE_FULFILLMENT_DATA_
                    [Marketplace] => xxx
                    [Merchant] => xxx
                    [SignatureMethod] => HmacSHA256
                    [SignatureVersion] => 2
                    [Timestamp] => 2012-04-04T11:42:54Z
                    [Version] => 2009-01-01
                    [Signature] => xxx=
                )
```

The response I'm getting this this, it's also the same that I get from the [scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html) if I enter the same data there.

```
Array
(
    [ErrorResponse] => Array
        (
            [xmlns] => http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/
            [Error] => Array
                (
                    [Type] => Sender
                    [Code] => AccessDenied
                    [Message] => Access to Feeds.SubmitFeed is denied
                )

            [RequestID] => bac7376f-1b2b-41ae-b2d2-de974b217ee7
        )

)
```

Besides the error from the API response I get "Insufficient user rights." when I try to access this URL https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/registration/register.html Ironically that's the URL amazon told me to sign up to after I've used the contact form...

Why do I get this error? What am I missing? Where in this damn mess of amazons thousand pages and registrations have I forgotten to signup or agree to something?

Comment: while registering process they ask for if it is you or your developer want to access Amazon API what did you select?

Answer (score 1):

Have you account in USA zone?

Maybe you should to change 'host' parameter

[host] => mws-de.amazonservices.com